# Selection by repeated field value

Tags: mysql, sql

There is the table PETS

`id | field_a | field_b`

Need to make a selection by coincidence one field, and that was more than a coincidence. 
for example

```
id | field_a | field_b
1  | cats    | 13
2  | cats    | 15
3  | cats    | 16
4  | dogs    | 15
5  | dogs    | 16
6  | birds   | 13
7  | birds   | 19
8  | birds   | 14
```

As a result, have obtained

```
cats
dogs
```

This result is obtained because only these records match more than one entry in the field_b (15 and 16).

Comment: Whats the Problme STatement?

Comment: "selection by coincidence" - never heard of it. will you exaplin

Comment: It looks like you want to return the distinct `field_a` for which `field_b` is not unique, is that correct?

Comment: @ninesided, yes. In example **cats** and **dogs** have equal values in **field_b** (15 and 16) and count of this records more 1

Comment: @AlexCoder but _cats_ and _birds_ both have rows with a value of 13 and are not included, why is that?

Answer (score 1):

You could try a query like this:

```
SELECT p1.field_a 
FROM pets p1 
INNER JOIN pets p2 ON (p1.field_b = p2.field_b AND p1.id != p2.id) 
GROUP BY p1.field_a,p2.field_a 
HAVING count(p1.field_b) > 1
```

Comment: No, because we don't know values in **field_b**

Comment: Ok i hope now i get what you want :) I have edited my answer. Now you will get only pets which match on at least 2 field_b values with a single other pet.